# replace lines in a larger file with ID

Tags: python, replace, line

Hello every one i have problem with replacing same content lines with same ID e.x:

```
ONE -----------> 1
TWO -----------> 2
THREE-----------> 3
HELLO-----------> 4
SEVEN-----------> 5
ONE-----------> 1
ONE-----------> 1
ONE-----------> 1
TWO-----------> 2
```

I have worked on this code below but with no results:
NOTE: filein and file2 have same value of the defined example.

```
# opening the file in read mode
file = open("filein.txt", "r")
# opening the file in read and write mod
file2 = open("filein2.txt", "r+")
replacement = ""
count=1
# using the for loop
for line in file:
 for line2 in file2:
  line = line.strip()
  if line == line2 :
   changes = line.replace(line, str(count))
   replacement = replacement + changes + "\n"
 file2.seek(0)
 file2.write(replacement)
 count=count+1
file.close()
```

filein and filein2 contain same value

```
ONE 
TWO
THREE
HELLO
SEVEN
ONE
ONE
ONE
TWO
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: why do `HELLO` and `SEVEN` both have an ID of 4? and what do you mean by _same content lines_? or do you have two files and want to put the IDs from one file to the other according to their line in file?

Comment: @barbosa you can [edit] your question and add that information there, also can you please show the contents of both files? and it is still pretty unclear what exactly you want to do

Comment: @barbosa to be clear both files have exactly the same contents? and you want to in either of those files replace text with ID (basically the index of the line that starts from 1, correct?)?

Comment: I want to replace the same content with same id using one file or two

Comment: @Matiiss In my case I have used tow files one to get the line one and for compared it with the value of the file 2 if it is equal i want to replace it by an id created by me in the code represent counter

Comment: @barbosa and if they are not equal they stay the same?

Comment: @Matiiss yes exactly in final i would like to get the same file or new file with same number of lines but with id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding this is what you want; compare two files line by line, if the corresponding lines are equal, assign an ID to them, if the lines repeat somewhere else in the file assign the same ID as before, if the lines have not occurred before assign a new ID. If the lines are different, get both of their contents. In the end write either the ID or line content to a new file:

```py
index_dct = dict()
id_ = 1

with open('text.txt') as f1, open('text1.txt') as f2, open('result.txt', 'w') as result:
    for line1, line2 in zip(f1, f2):
        line1, line2 = line1.strip(), line2.strip()
        if line1 == line2:
            text = index_dct.get(line1)
            if text is None:
                text = index_dct[line1] = id_
                id_ += 1
        else:
            text = f'{line1} {line2}'
        result.write(f'{text}\n')
```

A quick overview of how this works:

First you have a dictionary to store the value and its corresponding ID so that if a value repeats you can assign the same ID.

Then using a context manager (`with`) you open three files:
then iterate over the first two files at the same time using `zip` and compare if the lines match, if they do then first try to get their corresponding ID based on their value, if there is not yet such a value in the dictionary assign the current line value as a key and have its value be the ID, then increase ID by one.
If the lines don't match then just concatenate them together

Finally write the resultant value to the third file

Comment: I have get this  text = f'{line1} {line2}'
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @barbosa what version of python are you using? if it is older than `3.6` then you probably can replace it with this: `text = line1 + ' ' + line2` and this: `result.write(f'{text}\n')` with `result.write(str(text) + '\n')`

Comment: is this work for files that contain more than one million lines ?

Comment: @barbosa yes, why not? you can first also just test with smaller files

Comment: This is what i need exactly

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make each unique word have a unique ID, you could use a dictionary:

```
inputText = "ONE TWO THREE HELLO SEVEN ONE ONE ONE TWO"

indexDictionary = {}
count = 1

outList = []

for word in inputText.split(" "):
    if word not in indexDictionary.keys():
        indexDictionary[word] = count
        count += 1
    outList.append(indexDictionary[word])

print(outList)
print(indexDictionary)
```

Comment: but if I have a large file which contain more than 10000 lines how can  I edit it ?